# tkinter button to open new window and run script

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I have a tkinter button that I want to use to run an existing python script in a new cmd window. How would I do that?
I can get the new cmd window to appear, but how do I run the script in it?

Thanks,
Chris.

Comment: You did not say how you get a cmd window to appear, or what OS your are using, but read the doc for subprocess.POpen and experiment until you get it right.

Comment: Okay, I'm on Win7 and the code currently is:
`
from Tkinter import *
from sys import executable
from subprocess import Popen, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE
import os

def delprof():
 Popen(["cmd.exe"], creationflags=CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiline code is more readable if you edit your question to add it (allowed, just mark it as edited and say so in the comment) rather than in a comment.

```
from Tkinter import *
from sys import executable
from subprocess import Popen, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE
import os
def delprof(): Popen(["cmd.exe"], creationflags=CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE) `
```

If you get a console with a prompt, you can run python or do anything else.  To run a particular python program, the following works for me (3.4).

```
from tkinter import *
from subprocess import call

pyprog = 'tem2.py'
def callpy(): call(['python', '-i', pyprog] )

root = Tk()
Button(root, text='Run', command=callpy).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

When running a program, the console normally disappears when the program ends.  To prevent that with a python program, so output can be seen, either put something like

```
input('hit enter to exit')
```

at the end of the program or start it with '-i', as I did above.  This also allows execution of additional interactive statements to examine the result